# android how to get Imagebutton to the right with layout_height="match_parent"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to have a ImageButton to the right of 2 EditText

I have tried

`RelativeLayout`: but the `ImageView layout_height="match_parent"` does not work

`LinearLayout`: but cant get the button to the right side without being pushed out by the EditText's. LinearLayout's `LayoutDirection="rtl"` could have worked, but it does not exist anymore

edit:

i dont want to use specific values in width/height

i have this i put height 90dp for now, but i dont want it there

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/login"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/login"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <!-- TODO: FIX android:layout_height="match_parent" -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/login"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/login_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of following:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edtxt"
            android:contentDescription="@string/saveBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

OR

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

I updated your code. Check that. Its showing the output as you want in my emulator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/login_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:contentDescription="@string/username"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/uname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/login"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

      android:layout_below="@id/uname"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/login"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: So you want to use wrap_content only? Or something else?

Comment: the edit text need to be match_parent (or fill_parent if you prefere)  
i want the image to the right side of the view while edit text fills the rest of the view

Comment: the image i want to use is much smaller  
therefore i want height="match_parent" in the ImageButton  
but that does not work

Comment: Add property android:layout_centerInParent="true" in ImageButton. I think that will work. Don't change layout_height of ImageButton.

Comment: right now im using  
android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
as is shown in the xml i added  
if i use centerInParent it should get over/under the editText's  
but i'll try just to make sure.  
  
it dit not do what i thougt but it did exactly the same

Comment: Ok. Worked in my case. So just mentioned. Hope it works for you, too

Comment: did it work to get the full height of the parent? or just to make it look better because it is in the middle? that will not be enough with a small image. the image is 13x21

Comment: Ok. This will just align image in center. It will not change its height.

Comment: You want to increase height of imageview inside button or height of image button itself?

Comment: ... missed the weightSum thing. saw it now when i checked again. seems to be the only thing that works. but it should work in relativelayout as well

Answer (score 0):

Do you need smthg like below ?

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainscreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```